# Calling bash command with If/Else and awk

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, awk, s3cmd

I'm looking to GET all files on my S3 bucket that are larger than 200 KB. After some research, I'm able to recursively generate a list of all files in my S3 bucket that are larger than 200 KB, with the following command:

```
s3cmd ls -r s3://mybucket | awk '{if ($3 > 200000) print $4}' > files.txt
```

Instead of just generating a list, I would ideally like to not only find all files greater than 200KB, but also GET them in the same command.

It's something like this that I'm looking for, but it's clearly not correct.

```
s3cmd ls -r s3://mybucket | awk '{if ($3 > 200000) "s3cmd get $4" }'
```

For reference: if you're unfamiliar with s3cmd: $3 returns file size and $4 returns file name of a particular file returned by s3cmd.

Thanks for your help in advance.

#### Question:

**How do you call another bash command within another bash command with awk?**

Comment: awk is not a shell. Don't mangle your code with layers of nested calls (`shell { awk { system { shell { s3cmd } } } }`) to try to make it act like one, just let shell call awk and then operate on its results (`shell { awk | xargs s3cmd }`) like @GlennJackman shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s3cmd ls -r s3://mybucket | awk '$3 > 200000 {print $4}' | xargs s3cmd get
```

Comment: Usual warnings about filenames with whitespace apply here.

Comment: This post was marked as low quality. I'm recommending deletion. Please improve the quality of your post with an explanation and some qualifiers so that future users will understand.

Comment: @Jeremy This is a legitimate answer. It is not delete-worthy.

Comment: @Jeremy this is THE correct answer to this question, can't imagine why you'd want to delete it. It's very clear but if anyone has questions they can always ask.

Comment: I think `-d '\n'` is missing here.

Comment: Is there a way here to show which file is being downloaded? I think the current command "silently" downloads all files.

Comment: Is there an option to s3cmd to enable that? A "verbose" options perhaps?

Comment: s3cmd does show which file is being downloaded by default, however, it wasn't showing up when I was pairing it with xargs. Oh well.

Comment: does `s3cmd get` take multiple arguments or just one?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to executing binaries with arguments taken from text files, `bash` would be better as it's safe with expanding variables containing spaces as arguments.

```
while read -ra A; do
    [[ ${A[2]} -gt 200000 ]] && s3cmd get "${A[3]}"
done < <(s3cmd ls -r s3://mybucket)
```

Comment: That will interpret backslashes in the file names to, for example, convert a file named `foo\tbar` into `foo<tab>bar>` where `<tab>` represents a literal tab character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `system` function in `awk`:

```
s3cmd ls -r s3://mybucket | awk '($3 > 200000) { system("s3cmd get " $4); }'
```

Comment: what happened to the if?

Comment: `($3 > 200000)` is implicit if condition.

Comment: $4 seems like it's not getting passed into system("s3cmd get $4"), any thoughts about getting around this?

Comment: Can you try: `awk '($3 > 200000) { system("s3cmd get " $4); }'`

Comment: ah yes, that would do it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes I know ... need to finish this task to see if it really works.

Comment: If you execute `system("s3cmd get " $4)` - what will happen if `$4` contains shell globbing characters?